# will iOS universal links support work without web server?

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-universal-links

I have created an cordova iOS app and wanted to add universal links support to it with a custom domain. Means I don't have any web server to configure my app association file . But still i need to support my app to handle a custom domain link like abc.com/path/* . abc.com doesn't exist but i need to handle this links in my ios app. Same is working fine in Android. any custom non existing domain links are working fine in android. but the same is not the case for ios. Can some one please help me in this how can i achieve this.

I have already tried cordova-plugin-deeplinks to do the same. Android is working perfectly but ios is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom URL Scheme solved my problem. used cordova-plugin-customurlscheme plugin and configured my custom url schema.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not work. You need to host the `apple-app-site-association` file on that domain in order to prove ownership of the domain.

Otherwise, iOS wouldn't be able to prevent your app from hijacking e.g. twitter.com.

Comment: thanks fphilipe, is there any alternative way possible for ios to do this?

Comment: You could use Firebase to set up Dynamic Links with a custom subdomain such as example.page.link. Firebase will automatically host the correct apple-app-site-association file for you on that domain.